# How can I get Xcode 7 to keep around the logging output from the UI Test target?

Tags: xcode, logging, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I've started using the UI Test features of Xcode 7, and when I run a test, I get the output from testing showing up in the content pane of the debugging area.

However, as soon as the testing is finished, that output gets replaced by the logging from the application itself.

Is there a way to keep both sets of logged data visible?

Adding an example, of what I want to see:

[image: screenshot of Xcode showing where I want to see my messages to stdout/err]

Comment: Are you just looking to find the recorded information from the UI testing logs or are you asking for them to be displayed in the same window? I don't know if it's possible to have them show up together. I only see them in one place once the testing completes.

Comment: I'm able to see the results on the reporting tab by clicking and drilling down through the UI after the test is completed, but I'd like to be able to see the raw text that gets logged during the test run. Kind of a nice to have, since I find it easier to understand the patterns of what's available by looking at the raw output and doing text searches for keywords and identifiers versus spelunking through an expanding and contracting tree. Maybe I need to explore using the command line xcode tools?

Comment: hi @RobFagen where is the reporting tab? i was hoping for the output to remain too.

Comment: @m.y thanks for asking. I've added an image to clarify where I'm talking about.

Comment: cool! thanks @RobFagen :)

Answer (score 3):

Might not completely solve your issue: I was having a similar problem (and found your question!) and just found out that you can select *which* logging output is shown in the **Debug Area**:

[image]

Maybe, if you combine this with a cleverly inserted test breakpoint you might (partially) achieve what you were looking for ;-)

Comment: Only possible while test is running. When test ends, this is killed.