# Write custom strings to logs during UI testing / unit testing

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xcode-ui-testing

Is there any way to add text to the logs of a test?

Neither NSLog nor Swift.print seem to log any remaining text to any logs that I can see, when running UI and/or unit testing in Xcode 9. I am running on device.

Whatever I do, I do not see any NSLog/print stuff in Report navigator, clicking on the Test. I tried expanding everything...

Comment: Related for Xcode 7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159648/how-can-i-get-xcode-7-to-keep-around-the-logging-output-from-the-ui-test-target

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see print statements in the raw log for the test run but if you’re looking at the pretty GUI log that shows the test steps then you’ll need to use XCTContext.runActivity to “log” things and be able to see then there (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctcontext/2923506-runactivity). If this isn’t quite what you’re looking for you can add attachments (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/activities_and_attachments/adding_attachments_to_tests_and_activities) containing test data you’re interested in and consume them after the test run.

Comment: The attachments look promising. Will try next week. The print statements vanish as soon as tests end.

Comment: By raw log are you checking the `.log` file that gets created for a test session?

You can find it in Xcode 9.3 by going to the Test Navigator, tapping on Log, Selecting All Messages tab, expanding " Writing dianostic log" step, and opening the log file. I do a lot of print statements in my tests for setup/tear down steps and they show up here.